# Bar graphs with dynamic data

Tags: plugins

I want to show bar graphs on a page in my WordPress site. Data to show in graphs will be dynamic. Can anyone suggest me anyway where I can pass data/values to shortcode/formula and I will get a bar graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use paid plugin then there is no. of plugin available.

I suggest you once check below plugins:

**1. [Google Chart WordPress Plugin](http://codecanyon.net/item/google-chart-wordpress-plugin/6197635?s_phrase=&s_rank=2)**

This plugin use data is driven by built-in form or Google Spreadsheet and it's also responsive, work fine with small screen device.

**2. [Visualizer: Charts and Graphs](https://wordpress.org/plugins/visualizer/)**

The plugin provides a variety of charts that are optimized to address your data visualization needs. These charts are based on pure 
HTML5/SVG technology (adopting VML for old IE versions), so no extra plugins are required. To setup your chart data you need to upload 
it as a CSV file.

**3. [Easy Chart Builder for WordPress](http://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-chart-builder/)**

Easy Chart Builder for WordPress is the most popular chart plugin. It has 6 predefined charts:
- horizontal bar graph
- stacked horizontal bar graph
- vertical bar graph
- stacked vertical bar graph
- line graph
- pie chart

But creating charts with Easy Chart Builder for WordPress isn’t as straightforward as the other plugins on this list. To create a chart, 
you need to use a shortcode, in the format: `[easychart argument="value" …]`

Above three different plugin based on data use in contex data/values to shortcode/formula. You can check more features from it's website.

**EDIT**:
Example: use of Easy Chart Builder for WordPress by following steps:

> **1)** Install and activate this plugin 
>  **2)** Copy below example sortcode to
>   any post from admin side and check it in front post page. And the
>   result is vertical bar format display with show/hide table data
>   button.

```
[easychart type="vertbar" height="300" width="350" title="Your Title Here" groupnames="Chocolate, Vanilla, Strawberry, Mint, Peach" valuenames="1999, 2001, 2003, 2004, 2007, 2008" group1values="2069, 1184, 2389, 820, 2398, 701" group2values="2002, 1177, 2825, 697, 3226, 993" group3values="4071, 824, 505, 100, 230, 0" group4values="0, 163, 320, 145, 0, 121" group5values="0, 0, 143, 70, 565, 102"]
```

Let me know if there is any doubt/concern regarding this.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was using Easy Chart Builder, but in console it is showing following error thats why bar graph image is not displaying. Do you have any idea?
Uncaught ReferenceError: wpEasyChart is not defined

Comment: Please once check online documentation here: http://www.dyerware.com/main/products/easy-chart-builder/easy-chart-builder-plugin-for-wordpress.html. If you still facing same then please let me know I will focus on that.

Comment: Please check, I EDIT content with example(How to use). I can not see any error at my end.

Comment: Really thank you for your help. Easy chart js was not loading. I have added that js through my plugin and it is working now.

Comment: Great! Finally you got solution! Happy to Help!